# php loop for a status change monitoring

Tags: php, buffer

I am using PHP DOM to extract data from a webpage, then when I got the info that I needed I extract the link from next page and direct the code to that page and so on and so forth.

I'm monitoring some changes through this.

Everything is great, until I flow the buffer because it thinks php is stuck in a loop and breaks the code. I know I can incrase the timeout, but I was wondering if anyone know of a better way to structure this code please advise me.

Here is a basic flow chart

1. get address of first webpage
2. do data extraction
3. get next page address from within the page
4. use header to redirect to that page
5. go to step 1. Unless there is no next page, then stop

So most of the time I go through this loop 8-12 times before it kills the php. I need to keep doing this until I fulfill the flowchart. Anyway I can empty the buffer before going to next page. Btw, this whole thing is in one code "data.php

Comment: Trying to create your own P*RN filter are you?

Comment: look up php long running tasks. But in reality php is a poor choice for this kind of thing. Better to pick a language with threading and events built in.

Comment: @TimDinh LOL Good one! but no

Comment: @user574632 Yeah i thought that too. I am not really familiar with any language that would do this, any suggestions?!

Comment: Well thats a personal choice. I would choose C# because i am familiar with it, but most modern languages support these things.

Comment: @DavidCameron Don't run PHP from yourwebpage, run it in CLI. I create a lot of long running scripts for PHP in CLI. Works fine. Set `set_time_limit(0);` and if you run out of memory you need to adjust memory limit something like this: `ini_set('memory_limit', '4095M');`

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to use PHP as your script. You should run it as [CLI (Command Line Interface).](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command-line_interface)  Now I'm not sure if you actually wait for the extracted data to view(realtime) or just save your data somewhere for later use but there are several solutions.

If you just want to run a script one time only, or just manually whenever you want.  Make sure you have php installed in your unix or windows.

*Windows: Set your php directory in your PATH system variable then you can run `php  myscript.php` in your command window.*

*Unix: I'm sure you don't need an explanation ^^*

There are some [PHP CLI features](http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.php) if you need to ask for input or show some output etc .

If you really want some kind of webpage where you can press a button and your extracting will begin and you want to see data, well you can do some things to keep your browser working.

You can queue your extracting task and let it run by cronjob on the webserver every now and then.  Your data is available to view when the cronjob has ran the script and extracted all data.

You can also tell the cronjob to do this every hour for example and save extracted data for viewing purpose.

Or you can create an asynchronous call with Ajax [(jquery example)](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/), You'll still need to wait and stay on the page. But at least your browser isn't stuck.